# How best to display a point of interest extra information?

Tags: website-design, map-ui

I need to show points of interest on a map, and extra information when the user clicks the marker. For the extra information, I am thinking of either a popup on the map, or showing the information below/beside the map.

I'm wondering if there is any best practices for how to do this? I've tried to find some to no avail. Otherwise I will probably just go with my personal opinion, that in map popups are annoying.

Comment: I don't know what you're making, but consider that sites like Google/Bing/Yahoo Maps are now effectively "standards" for map UI, and have millions of users. So you may want to lean towards following their implementation if only because that's how many users will expect things to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both solutions are perfectly acceptable, make your choice taking these points into consideration:

- the popup on the map may hide other useful information
- more than a very few popups quickly becomes cluttered. It's ok if only one of them is open at a time
- the amount of information in a popup must remain small

On the other side, showing information beside the map:

- you loose the connection with the point of interest, so you have to add a visual relation (a color, a number, an icon, a line...) with the point on the map. This connection becomes tricky or hard to read when you have a lot of points
- some scrolling / window resizing may be necessary for the user to see the extra information